# Grabbing a text title using regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to define an eager regular expression which is able to grap a complete "title" from a flat text document.
It should start with a letter (case insensitive), can contains up to 5 words, and each word may contain numbers. It should end when 2 spaces are found.

I am parsing each row at a time, and the title can startat  any location in the row.

Example:

```
11/20/2011      this is the 1st document title   written by:user
Hi,
This is a sample text which is not the title since it does not end with 2 spaces.
```

Once parsing each of the rows, only the first row should return a match "this is the 1st document title".

Thanks

Comment: If all titles start with a date and you check for that, it will improve the speed of execution greatly.

Comment: Your title has 6 words unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Also looks like you could just split on multiple whitespace and take the second element.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the row starts with a date and if it does then read the hole row

Here is the regex for reading if the row starts with a date: `^([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})(.*?)\n`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing this, but if you must:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s(\\w+(?:\\s\\w+){0,5})\\s{2}", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(text);

if (match.find())
    System.out.println(match.group(1));
```

Replace `if` with `while` if you need to find more titles in the same string (here called text). This finds titles with 1-6 words, since your title has 6 words (not 5), like FailedDev mentioned in the comments.

Like I mentioned in the comment, and Erik Larsson repeated, it would be much faster to read line by line and anchor your match to the beginning of the string.